# Angular material 2 autocomplete with add new listitem to it

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material2

[image]i am looking for angular material 2 autocomplete for work autocomplete functionality with if no match found it should give an option to add it to the list.. its will perfect if anyone do it using formly thing but its fine with regular code as well..
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please show your current code so far?

Comment: currently i am working on example given angular material document for autocomplete with addition to it i would like to add one functionality for add new list item if not present in list
https://stackblitz.com/angular/gqgqdyddlvk?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts

Comment: I try to use one plugin called "Selectize" for do stuff but it not having UI or behavior like material does
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-selectize

Comment: please check attached image to questions you will get better idea regarding

Comment: i don't know if is option for you, but you can use [select-2](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2) who do the job, unfortunatly this lib require jQuery to work :(

Comment: unfortunately select-2 is not useful to me, same functionalities provided by angular material itself. do you have any other approach

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your code is responsible for returning the filtered list of options, you can have the filter function return a special option when no results are found. You can add an `optionSelected` callback function so that when an option is selected, you can check for the special option and take an appropriate action such as adding the option to the list or launching a dialog. The callback function should also set the new option as the input value via the FormControl object or model.

Here's a very basic [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzf9dw?embed=1&file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts).

Comment: Thank you it will help me to develop own code like Selectize stuff